# UE4 How to set pitch in controlRotation for AIController

Tags: unreal-engine4

I try setControlRotation but Pitch always ignore that. It works only for Yaw

Also i tried set Pitch in animation bluprint. Seems that somthing change it before animation bluprint, beacose Pitch tried to return in to previous value

Comment: Can you clarify more about what you are trying to do? Is the AI a shooter enemy? Is it a car/plane? You'll also need to write your code here for us to find out where exactly you are wrong

Comment: Now i found that really i need is SetFocus, but i can't make it turn smoothly. I making simple shooter and its all for enemies ai

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/897656/ai-setfocus-instantly-snap-rotate-to-location-how.html

Answer (score 0):

at the end i make aiming through creating special simple pawn:

1. create pawn
2. setFocus on that pawn
3. move pawn to enemy's head

Answer (score 0):

The default AIController overrides pitch in this function.  You'll need to make a new parent to get the other features of AIController.

```
void AEEAIController::UpdateControlRotation(float DeltaTime, bool bUpdatePawn)
{
    APawn* const MyPawn = GetPawn();
    if (MyPawn)
    {
        FRotator NewControlRotation = GetControlRotation();

        // Look toward focus
        const FVector FocalPoint = GetFocalPoint();
        if (FAISystem::IsValidLocation(FocalPoint))
        {
            NewControlRotation = (FocalPoint - MyPawn->GetPawnViewLocation()).Rotation();
        }
        else if (bSetControlRotationFromPawnOrientation)
        {
            NewControlRotation = MyPawn->GetActorRotation();
        }

        // We override this so flying units can go up and down
        //// Don't pitch view unless looking at another pawn
        //if (NewControlRotation.Pitch != 0 && Cast<APawn>(GetFocusActor()) == nullptr)
        //{
        //  NewControlRotation.Pitch = 0.f;
        //}

        SetControlRotation(NewControlRotation);

        if (bUpdatePawn)
        {
            const FRotator CurrentPawnRotation = MyPawn->GetActorRotation();

            if (CurrentPawnRotation.Equals(NewControlRotation, 1e-3f) == false)
            {
                MyPawn->FaceRotation(NewControlRotation, DeltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```